# How to find out if a domain is using DKIM

Tags: email, dkim

If I receive an email from A.com without DKIM-Signature in the header, how could I know if A.com is using DKIM?

I am trying to figure out if a domain is using DKIM, but if I didn't or can't receive an email from A.com, how could I konw if A.com is using DKIM?

Comment: without a zone transfer or email w/dkim there is no reliable way to know for sure.

Comment: @JacobEvans evena zone transfer will only tell you that it is configured, not that it is being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With DKIM alone, there is no way to be sure. [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org) is designed for validating that email **content** is trustworthy i.e. hasn't changed during delivery. The key used for signing is verified against public DKIM key in DNS, but the same domain can have several keys for different purposes and the *selector* can be anything, e.g. `mta1._domainkey` or `whatever._domainkey` and is only introduced in the *flag* `s=selectorname` of `DKIM-Signature` header.

If the sender has also implemented [DMARC](https://dmarc.org), it is a clear indication that there should be both DKIM and [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/Introduction). Therefore:

- If a domain has `_dmarc.example.com. TXT "v=DMARC1; p=...` there should be DKIM. The DMARC record also tells what to do with messages not passing the test.
- If there is no `_dmarc TXT`, they may or may not have  DKIM.

Comment: RFC 7489 says that Identifier Alignment occurs when "SPF or DKIM (or both)" are valid.  So it's possible for a sender to use DMARC without DKIM, although in practice that seems very rare.

Answer (score 0):

Send an e-mail to Gmail address... Check source headers? also if it went to spam DKIM is probably not configured correctly.

Also https://www.mail-tester.com/ Is a great tool for configuration of DomainKeys, DKIM, DMARC & SPF.

Comment: This is answering a different question "how to determine if my emails are correctly dkim signed"